# Finding the last row in SSIS Script Component

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS 2008 script component and it uses the method

> Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer
>   Row)

to process the Rows. Is there a way to find if the Row I'm reading is the Last Row in the Dataset.

Comment: What do you want to do when you find the last row?

Comment: Based on the last row I need to write some custom logic.

Comment: Is the logic just going to affect that final row, the dataset as a whole, or populate a variable or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this before, but before your Script Component, add a RowCount Task and set the value of a variable (called RowCnt, initialised to 0 here) in this task.  Then in your script, have something like this (ensure the variable declaration is scoped in the Class)...

```
Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent

Dim iRows As Integer

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    iRows = iRows + 1
    If iRows = Variables.RowCnt Then
        'Do something here
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

That should allow you to process the final row.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (Row.EndOfRowset()) { // this is the last row }
```

Comment: I've just tested this pattern on BI tool for Visual Studio and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

The solution of overriding InputRows_ProcessInput worked for me.  However, don't use the code litterally.  The name of the method depends on the name of your Input.  In my case the method signature was:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
```

An easy way to find out the correct method is to go in the script and type "**base.Input**" intellisense should provide you the correct method to override.

```
public override void **Input0_ProcessInput**(**Input0Buffer** Buffer)
    {
        while (Buffer.NextRow())
        {
            Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
        }

        if (Buffer.EndOfRowset()) 
        {
            //do something 
        }
    }
```

Simply checking for "Buffer.EndOfRowset()" is not sufficient and it *doesn't work inside* the "while (Buffer.NextRow())" loop.  So I guess the "EndOfRowset" occurs after the last row.

Comment: "Something to consider. Simply checking for "Buffer.EndOfRowset()" was not sufficient in my case." Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. As far as I can tell, the part where you check for `EndOfRowset` is the only part of your answer that is actually designed to answer the question. Are you saying the answer you gave doesn't work?

Comment: The answer I gave works.  What doesn't work is using the `EndOfRowset` _within_ or _without_ the while loop.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Override the InputRows_ProcessInput method as follows:

```
public override void InputRows_ProcessInput(InputRowsBuffer Buffer)
    {

        while (Buffer.NextRow())
        {
            InputRows_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
        }

        if (Buffer.EndOfRowset()) 
        {
            //do something 
        }

    }
```

Comment: EndOfRowset does not seem to ever work- I'm using asynchronous transformation. It is never found to be true

Answer (score 0):

The custom script code is written inside the ScriptMain class. This class inherits from UserComponent which contains a virtual method FinishOutputs(). You can override this in ScriptMain to execute the code you need to run after the last row.

Relevant code in UserComponent.

```
public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, string InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
{

    if (InputName.Equals(@"Input 0", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Input0_ProcessInput(new Input0Buffer(Buffer, GetColumnIndexes(InputID), OutputMap));
    }

    if (Buffer.EndOfRowset)
    {
        InputsFinished = InputsFinished + 1;
        if (InputsFinished == 1)
        {
            FinishOutputs();
            MarkOutputsFinished();
        }
    }

}

public virtual void FinishOutputs()
{
}
```

Notice that this code is auto-generated and cannot be changed. It does however effectively give you place to put your code as you can override FinishOutputs() in your code within ScriptMain like this:

```
public override void FinishOutputs()
{
   //do stuff
}
```